# spring rest multiple filter

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, spring-rest

i have an entity  for i.e stock table ( attribute item, quantity, weight, expiration date .. ecc)...
how can do a dynamic query on my rest spring backend ? For i.e the user can do a query without filter but can also do a query with multiple filter for i,e quantity>0 and item = x and expiration data > yesterday... so i have to  develop the parse to accept not a fixed number of parameters. My second question is that my rest api must accept = as operator but also < > >= <= != to do filter query.
Thanks

Comment: For the first part using Spring Data's QueryDsl support would be a possibility. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41148216/spring-jpa-custom-query-with-combination-of-parameters-in-where-condition/41151516#41151516 However if the user can also specify the operators then I feel that handling these in custom manner is the only option.

Comment: Hi Alan,thanks with dsl i m able to do flexible query. Im also able to do join from table ? How can i m able to understand what filter used in rest request the user and parse it in order to do the correct dsl query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if spring provides any such functionality. You will have to take the conditions for your filters in a map, build an expression parser and then build queries at run time.

I would say a better solution is to look at graphql.

http://graphql.org/

Spring has support for GraphQL https://github.com/oembedler/graphql-spring-boot

Comment: criteria build can be a correct solution ? http://www.baeldung.com/rest-search-language-spring-jpa-criteria

Comment: @dariofrongi yes if you want a simple solution then stick with this approach. GraphQL is more involved solution.